# Map clear in scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, dictionary, apache-spark

Problem Statement:

When i try to clear the Map columns, the columns part of the handlers Map also gets cleared. Any way of avoiding that ?

```
def getTransformations(configuration: NodeSeq) {
var id: Int = 0
var methodCall: String = ""
val completeTransformation = Map[Int, Map[String, Map[String, String]]]()
val transformationsMap = Map[Int, Map[String, Map[String, String]]]()
val handlers = Map[String, Map[String, String]]()
val columns = Map[String, String]()

for (transformations <- configuration \\ "transformations") {
  for (transformation <- transformations \\ "transformation") {
    id += 1
    for (handler <- transformation \\ "handler") {
       for (input <- handler \\ "input") {
           columns.+=(((input \\ "@name").mkString) -> input.text)
      }
      handlers(handler.attribute("type").mkString) = columns
      columns.clear()
    }
    transformationsMap(id) = handlers
    handlers.clear()
   }
 }
transformationsMap
}
```

Example:
[As seen in the image the handlers Map is build using the columns Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyj5l.jpg)

[When the columns.clear is executed, its value in handlers Map is also cleared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OIv6.jpg)

Comment: handlers.clear() is tis intentional ?

Comment: I have added a few screenshot of the debug see if that helps

Comment: i need to clear them so that can use the same to add another set of values to the final Map

Comment: Don't use mutable maps

Comment: @Dima Any specific reasons ?

Comment: Oh, plenty. They are racy, not referentially transparent, they make code harder to debug, maintain, and reason about ... In general, they are just not idiomatic in scala. You also have to clear them, and sometimes other stuff gets cleared ;) ... If you are keen to writing code like this, you are much better off with java or ruby. Scala isn't the right tool for this.

Comment: @Dima Scala is just as capable or better at using mutable structures than Java or Ruby.  The difference is Scala make using immutable structures easier.  Yes immutability should be preferred but if you want to use mutable data there's no reason to switch languages.

Comment: @puhlen "no reason to switch languages" - my point exactly :) Stay with a language where imperative programming is idiomatic. 
Scala is more complex, and less efficient than java and _a lot_ more complex than ruby or python. If you are not going to use the benefits it provides, there is no reason to incur the costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, the "scala" way to write what you are trying to do here is something like this:

```
 val transformationsMap = (configuration \\ "transformations")
    .flatMap(_ \\ "transformation") 
    .zipWithIndex
    .map { case (trf, idx) => (idx+1) -> trf }
    .toMap
    .mapValues(_ \\ "handler)
    .mapValues {
      _.map { h => h.attribute("type").mkString -> (h \\ "input") }
       .toMap
       .mapValues { 
         _.map { in => (in \\ "@name".mkString) -> in.text }
           .toMap
       }                 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the scala way of doing it :) Would be great if you could help me on a few pointers which would make it easier for me to understand the language. I am new to the language BTW.

Answer (score 0):

```
handlers(handler.attribute("type").mkString) = columns
columns.clear()
```

you are setting just reference `columns` to `handlers` not the values.
the moment you clear the `columns`, you are removing values from the memory of `columns` reference and in `handlers` where you have reference to `columns` is also reflecting the change. Tats all. To avoid this issue, crate new copy of `columns` and assign it to `handler`.

```
 handlers(handler.attribute("type").mkString) =  collection.mutable.Map[String,String]() ++= columns
```

Its upto you, that you want mutable or immutable map while creating new copy .